# How to init base class staic inline data member in derived class?

Tags: c++, templates, static, c++17, class-template

Say I am having a class like

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

template<typename CharT>
class base
{
   //.....
public:
   using string_type = std::basic_string<CharT>;
   static inline string_type var;
   //.....
};

class derived : public base<char>
{
private:
   using base<char>::var;
public:
   static base<char>::string_type get()
   {
      return var;
   }
};

//template<>
//base<char>::string_type base<char>::var = "Value";

int main()
{
   std::cout << derived::get();
}
```

`base` class accept a `char` type and creates a string type for that class, but I want to use that `strng_type` string in the class, so I created a `static string_type` variable that has to set by the user of the class.

For `char` the value is `"Value"` and For `wchar_t` value is `L"Value"`. so I want to hide the `var` from a user by inheriting the class in specified type(`char`) now how to init that `var`.

I  have tried by removing the `inline` and uncomment the template it works but there is a way to init `inline static` base class variable.

1. How to init base class inline static data member?
2. It is a good idea doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to init base class inline static data member?

Remove the `inline` and you should be [able to initialize the `var`](https://godbolt.org/z/nco8cY)

```
template<typename CharT>
class base
{
public:
   using string_type = std::basic_string<CharT>;
   static string_type var;
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};

template<>
base<char>::string_type base<char>::var = "Value";

template<>
base<wchar_t>::string_type base<wchar_t>::var = L"Value";
```

---

> It is a good idea doing like this?

Not sure about the design. Because what you mentioned here

> "*I want to hide the `var` from a user by inheriting the class in*
> *specified type(`char`)* [...]"

It looks like, it is still accessible via

```
std::cout << base<char>::var;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am going to change public to protected in base class :-)